# Row based permissions in Django

Tags: django, django-permissions, django-guardian

I have a simple Django model which looks roughly like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from mylogapp.models import LogType

class Log(models.Model):
    responsible_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    description = models.TextField()
    log_type = models.ForeignKey(LogType)
```

There will be several million rows in the database table.

Row based permission for the django admin interface should get implemented.

If the current user is in the "responsible_group", then he is allowed to see and modify it.

AFAIK django guardian is not well suited for this. See this related page: https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/performance.html

Even solution "Direct foreign keys" does not match. The current model already contains everything which is needed to filter the rows.

How to enable row-based-permission for django and use the Log model for permission checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does using [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) help?

```
class LogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(responsible_group__in=request.user.groups.all())
```

Comment: Looks good. This way we do not need a third-party tool to enable row-based-permissions. Thank you for this answer!